# How a group of groups is called?

Tags: group-theory

How is a group of groups is called ? I'd like to give you an example. Assume we have $4$ symbols: $a, b, c, d$. One group $E_1$ is $\{a\rightarrow b, b\rightarrow a\}$. Another group $E_2$ is $\{c\rightarrow d, d\rightarrow c\}$, assume that there is also $F$ group with $\{b\rightarrow c, c\rightarrow b, a\rightarrow d, d\rightarrow a\}$ transitions. How would you call a group which inludes all groups $E_1, E_2$ and $F$ ? Supergroup? Overgroup? Group of groups? What name is accepted in the mathematical community?

Comment: I think you mean *set*, not *group*, which is way another thing in mathematics...

Comment: What you're describing look like permutations, do you mean to refer to the groups generated by those permutations? You may need to edit your post for clarification.

This may or may not answer your question: if the elements of a group A are contained within a group B, B is a supergroup of A, and A is a subgroup of B.

Comment: Overgroup. ${}{}$

Comment: Igor, do you basically mean a group with a set of distinguished subgroups? For example, in the example you give, we can think of $E_1,E_2$ and $F$ as distinguished subgroups of $\mathrm{Sym}(\{a,b,c,d\})$.

Comment: What I am describing in physical world are actions... I do mean group, not any general set... It seems "supergroup" is what what I am looking for. Thank you! Can the therm "overgroup" be used? Supergroup sounds too superior for non mathematicians. I read in wiki that:
"Supergroup, a rarely used term in mathematics for the counterpart of a subgroup". Why is it rarely used? It seems that mathematics should go from simple to complex, so simple groups should be studied first, than, more complex groups, groups of groups or "supergroups"? It seems to me the research went in opposite way: from groups

Comment: It is rarely used because overgroup is used more, and even more than that, subgroup is used (because any claim involving the term overgroup can be turned into a claim involving the more familiar term subgroup, trivially). Also, you're supposed to respond in comments or edit your question, not post updates in the form of "answers" to your question.

Comment: Thank you - one more vote for "overgroup". ( But wiki does not know about it ).
Yes, set of distinguished subgroups.. They are operating, but sometimes switch using transitions from F.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I am not used to percularities of this group yet.. ( and the system did not allow me to comment until I've got "rank 50", now I guess I've got it.. Leveling is high here..

Comment: You're always able to comment on your own questions (and answers to your own questions). You won't be able to comment on other questions yet.

Comment: The term "overgroup" is mentioned on Wikipedia's article on "subgroup" (but the term supergroup does not appear there). Also, you mean transpositions, not transitions.

Comment: I still don't understand your question.  Are you using "group" in the [technical mathematical sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) of a set equipped with a binary operation satisfying certain properties?  If so, then I don't understand your notation $\{a \to b, b \to a\}$ for defining a group: what is the set and what is the operation?  If not, then what *do* you mean?

Comment: Thank you, I think you gave me the perfect answers "supergroup" or "overgroup". But I just want to clarify my question, since it is, yes, not very clear.

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the perfect answers "supergroup" or "overgroup". But I just want to clarify my question, since it is not clear. May be you can help me to specify it correctly? Let me decribe you it. Assume there is x. It can take 2 values: a or b. The operation is: if x==a then x=b else if x==b then x=a. So, if I abbreviate transition of x from a to b as just a, and transition of x from b to a just as b, I can have abababa, or babababa, but not aaa. Inverse of a is b, inverse of b is a. I guess it is a group? E2 is similar and F includes them all and some other like trans from b to c

Comment: @NateEldredge As Cameron points out, OP is describing elements of permutation groups.

Comment: @anon I have never encountered the term "overgroup" before. I occasionally use supergroup, because it is like "superset". However, I avoid using such a term in something for other people to read as when I have used it people have done a double-take...

Comment: When I see "supergroup" I think Menudo. When I see "overgroup" I think weird Nietzschean mathematics. I vote for "hellagroup."

Comment: How about a "compound group" ?

Comment: For those who are asking about an operation: I just omitted an operation, because it is not relevant for my quesiton. Any operation will go. My question is a question of ternimnology.

Answer (score 3):

As G. H. Faust points out in the comments, what you appear to be describing here is not, in fact, a group of groups. A group is a set on which there is a [binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example_of_a_commutative_non-associative_magma) having certain properties. Rather, you seem to be describing groups of [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). In particular, using Cauchy's two-line notation, you've specifically mentioned the following permutations: $$E_1=\pmatrix{a & b & c & d\\b & a & c & d}\\E_2=\pmatrix{a & b & c & d\\a & b & d & c}\\F=\pmatrix{a & b & c & d\\d & c & b & a}$$ Calling the group of permutations of $a,b,c,d$ by the name $S_4,$ it can be shown that if $G$ is the smallest subgroup of $S_4$ containing $E_1,E_2,$ and $F,$ then $G$ is isomorphic to the group $\Bbb Z_2^3,$ which is the set of ordered binary triples with [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) as the operation.

Comment: No. I just omitted an operation, because it is not relevant for my quesiton. Any operation will go. My question is a question of ternimnology. It looks like there are variants "supergroup" and "overgroup". For the reason that "super" usually means something, well, SUPER-good, or SUper-man, meaning the super of all supers, the most super, superior, I incine to use "overgroup". But, is it understandable?

Comment: I think it's understandable, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand your question.

You would say: let $G$ denote a subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(\{a,b,c,d\})$ with the property that $G$ is an upper bound for $\{E_1,E_2,F\}$.